# Where can I see which permission you get with X number of points?

Tags: support, privileges

I've just reached 1500 points on stackoverflow. Previously I could go to my account and see which permissions I get for each category of points.

But something has changed and now I cannot find this page any more. can anyone help?

Comment: You want the [privileges page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here it is:

[image: screenshot]

Just hover the mouse over your own display name on top to open that card and see all the links you can't find anymore. This is global in the whole network, the screenshot from Meta is just an example.

Comment: `-1` That circle is not **red** enough

Comment: Hah! So *that's* where they moved the link. I haven't been able to find it for months since clicking on your score was changed to do something else. I've just been typing in the URL manually when I want to link it... Seen that dropdown hundreds of times and never paid any attention to the links at the top.

Comment: @Cody lol, glad to enlighten your eyes! :)

Comment: @ama we have enough reddish/brownish color around!

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd true, true...

Comment: Thanks a lot. The same is here: seen it hundreds of times and never been able to realize that the menu opens on hover.